# how to connect oracle database from python from unix server

Tags: python, oracle, unix

How to connect oracle database server from python inside unix server ?
I cant install any packages like cx_Orcale, pyodbc etc.
Please consider even PIP is not available to install.

It my UNIX PROD server, so I have lot of restriction.

I tried to run the sql script from sqlplus command and its working.

Comment: If you can't install any packages, then you will not be able to access Oracle from python. With that said, WHY can't you install any packages? If it is a company policy, you must point out to them that they are asking you to do the impossible.

Comment: That essentially means you would be working with both hands tied and got to resort to some sub-optimal  workarounds rather than doing it the right way. So, in this case the right approach is to have a word with your management/leads and showcase your persuasion skills and convince them about the right approach!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to connect Oracle database via SQLPLUS and I am calling the script with below way :

```
os.environ['ORACLE_HOME'] = '<ORACEL PATH>'
os.chdir('<DIR NAME>')
VARIBALE=os.popen('./script_to_Call_sql_script.sh select.sql').read()
```

My shell script: script_to_Call_sql_script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
envFile=ENV_FILE_NAME
envFilePath=<LOACTION_OF_ENV>${envFile}
ORACLE_HOME=<ORACLE PATH>

if  [[ $# -eq 0 ]]
then
      echo "USAGES: Please provide the positional parameter"
      echo "`$basename $0` <SQL SCRIPT NAME>"
fi

ECR=`$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s /@<server_name><<EOF
set pages 0
set head off
set feed off
@$1;
exit
EOF`

echo $ECR
```

Above things help me to do my work done on Production server.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so there is sqlplus and it works, this means that oracle drivers are there.

Try to proceed as follows:

1) create a python virtualenv in your $HOME. In python3

```
python -m venv $HOME/my_venv
```

2) activate it

```
source $HOME/my_venv/bin/activate[.csh]  # .csh is for cshell, for bash otherwise
```

3) install pip using python binary from you new virtualenv, it is well described here: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

TL;DR:

- curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
- python get_pip.py  (this should install pip into your virtualenv as $HOME/my_env/bin/pip[3]

4) install cx_Oracle:

```
pip install cx_Oracle
```

Now you should be able to import it in your python code and connect to an oracle DB.

Comment: Did you read the full question? The OP stated "Please consider even PIP is not available to install. ".

Comment: maybe he is just not aware of the fact that it can be installed locally without elevated privilieges?

Comment: pip is disable on server.. Its a working critical PROD server so thousand heads against me to restrict the installation of cx_Oracle from out side world.

Comment: and how is it disabled? on a networking level that it cannot download packages?

Comment: @RadekHofman Its Production server, i am expecting on one server only. it make it install it should be globalize for all server